# tortoisehg ImportError: DLL load failed: Access is denied

Tags: importerror, tortoisehg

The code is as follows:

```
#!python
** Mercurial version (4.4.2).  TortoiseHg version (4.4.2)
** Command: 
** CWD: C:\Windows\system32
** Encoding: cp1252
** Extensions loaded: 
** Python version: 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Windows version: sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=2, build=9200, platform=2, service_pack='')
** Processor architecture: unknown (failed to import win32api)
** Qt-5.9.2 PyQt-5.9.1 QScintilla-2.10.2.dev1711012104
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\workbench.pyo", line 717, in openRepo
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\repotab.pyo", line 117, in openRepo
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\repotab.pyo", line 383, in _createRepoWidget
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\thgrepo.pyo", line 670, in openRepoAgent
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\thgrepo.pyo", line 397, in startMonitoringIfEnabled
  File "tortoisehg\util\paths.pyo", line 130, in is_on_fixed_drive
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 145, in __getattr__
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 90, in _load
  File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
  File "win32file.pyo", line 12, in <module>
  File "win32file.pyo", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: Access is denied.
```

Hi. I got this error when I tried to access my repository. (It didn't even proceed to the push/pull window that lists previous commits). Why did this happen and how do I resolve it?

Thanks all.

Comment: additional info. i am using a 64bit Windows 10 pro

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it but i dont know which one of the steps that I did that fix it. so let me know if some else had this issue and please respond which one of the steps that i did that fixed it.. or if you got other ways of fixing it post your answers as well.

- Revert back my version of TortoiseHG from 4.4.2 to 4.2.0
- Move ".hg" folder from local directory to somewhere else(desktop) then put it back to your original directory.

  - Note: I did a restart as this seems to cause the windows explorer to hang
- On your ".hg" folder you'll have a hgrc file open that file and
  comment [tortoisehg] block of the file.

Working again for me :)